# Show all the Products in product filters magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, category-products, magento2.4.6

I create an attribute name **[show_category]** with yes/no values if it's set to yes then the product show on the category page but if it's select no, then product not shown on category page.

I create a module and override the file **Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\collection.php**

Using this module, I stop showing products which have the attribute **show_category** to **no** in frontend.

But now I want to show all the products in product filter, either the product with **show_category** to **no** or with **yes**.

Here is the code which I have use to show the products on category page :

File path :  Test\Cat\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\collection.php

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Test\Cat\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext;

use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\DefaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\DefaultFilterStrategyApplyCheckerInterface;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\TotalRecordsResolverInterface;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\TotalRecordsResolverFactory;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchCriteriaResolverInterface;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchCriteriaResolverFactory;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchResultApplierFactory;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchResultApplierInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\SizeResolverInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\RequestGenerator;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\EmptyRequestDataException;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\NonExistingRequestNameException;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\ProductLimitationFactory;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection as ParentCollection;

/**
 * Fulltext Collection
 *
 * This collection should be refactored to not have dependencies on MySQL-specific implementation.
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CookieAndSessionMisuse)
 */
class Collection extends ParentCollection
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $queryText;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $searchRequestName;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface
     */
    private $search;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
     */
    private $searchResult;

    /**
     * @var SearchResultFactory
     */
    private $searchResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder
     */
    private $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaResolverFactory
     */
    private $searchCriteriaResolverFactory;

    /**
     * @var SearchResultApplierFactory
     */
    private $searchResultApplierFactory;

    /**
     * @var TotalRecordsResolverFactory
     */
    private $totalRecordsResolverFactory;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $searchOrders;

    /**
     * @var DefaultFilterStrategyApplyCheckerInterface
     */
    private $defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory $eavEntityFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\State $catalogProductFlatState
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory $productOptionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Url $catalogUrl
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement
     * @param mixed $catalogSearchData
     * @param mixed $requestBuilder
     * @param mixed $searchEngine
     * @param mixed $temporaryStorageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface|null $connection
     * @param string $searchRequestName
     * @param SearchResultFactory|null $searchResultFactory
     * @param ProductLimitationFactory|null $productLimitationFactory
     * @param MetadataPool|null $metadataPool
     * @param \Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface|null $search
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder|null $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder|null $filterBuilder
     * @param SearchCriteriaResolverFactory|null $searchCriteriaResolverFactory
     * @param SearchResultApplierFactory|null $searchResultApplierFactory
     * @param TotalRecordsResolverFactory|null $totalRecordsResolverFactory
     * @param DefaultFilterStrategyApplyCheckerInterface|null $defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory $eavEntityFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Helper $resourceHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory $universalFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\State $catalogProductFlatState,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory $productOptionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Url $catalogUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement,
        $catalogSearchData = null,
        $requestBuilder = null,
        $searchEngine = null,
        $temporaryStorageFactory = null,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        $searchRequestName = 'catalog_view_container',
        SearchResultFactory $searchResultFactory = null,
        ProductLimitationFactory $productLimitationFactory = null,
        MetadataPool $metadataPool = null,
        \Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface $search = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder = null,
        SearchCriteriaResolverFactory $searchCriteriaResolverFactory = null,
        SearchResultApplierFactory $searchResultApplierFactory = null,
        TotalRecordsResolverFactory $totalRecordsResolverFactory = null,
        DefaultFilterStrategyApplyCheckerInterface $defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker = null
    ) {
        $this->searchResultFactory = $searchResultFactory
            ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SearchResultFactory::class);
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $eavConfig,
            $resource,
            $eavEntityFactory,
            $resourceHelper,
            $universalFactory,
            $storeManager,
            $moduleManager,
            $catalogProductFlatState,
            $scopeConfig,
            $productOptionFactory,
            $catalogUrl,
            $localeDate,
            $customerSession,
            $dateTime,
            $groupManagement,
            $catalogSearchData,
            $requestBuilder,
            $searchEngine,
            $temporaryStorageFactory,
            $connection,
            $searchRequestName,
            $searchResultFactory,
            $productLimitationFactory,
            $metadataPool,
            $search,
            $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            $filterBuilder,
            $searchCriteriaResolverFactory,
            $searchResultApplierFactory,
            $totalRecordsResolverFactory,
            $defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker
        );
        $this->searchRequestName = $searchRequestName;
        $this->search = $search ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface::class);
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder::class);
        $this->searchCriteriaResolverFactory = $searchCriteriaResolverFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(SearchCriteriaResolverFactory::class);
        $this->searchResultApplierFactory = $searchResultApplierFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(SearchResultApplierFactory::class);
        $this->totalRecordsResolverFactory = $totalRecordsResolverFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(TotalRecordsResolverFactory::class);
        $this->defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker = $defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(DefaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get search.
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return \Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface
     */
    private function getSearch()
    {
        if ($this->search === null) {
            $this->search = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface::class);
        }
        return $this->search;
    }

    /**
     * Test search.
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @param \Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface $object
     * @return void
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    public function setSearch(\Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface $object)
    {
        $this->search = $object;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria builder.
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private function getSearchCriteriaBuilder()
    {
        if ($this->searchCriteriaBuilder === null) {
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);
        }
        return $this->searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria builder.
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder $object
     * @return void
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    public function setSearchCriteriaBuilder(\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder $object)
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $object;
    }

    /**
     * Get filter builder.
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder
     */
    private function getFilterBuilder()
    {
        if ($this->filterBuilder === null) {
            $this->filterBuilder = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder::class);
        }
        return $this->filterBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Set filter builder.
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $object
     * @return void
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    public function setFilterBuilder(\Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $object)
    {
        $this->filterBuilder = $object;
    }

    /**
     * Apply attribute filter to facet collection
     *
     * @param string $field
     * @param mixed|null $condition
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
    {
        if ($this->searchResult !== null) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Illegal state');
        }

        $this->getSearchCriteriaBuilder();
        $this->getFilterBuilder();
        if (!is_array($condition) || !in_array(key($condition), ['from', 'to'], true)) {
            $this->filterBuilder->setField($field);
            $this->filterBuilder->setValue($condition);
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->create());
        } else {
            if (!empty($condition['from'])) {
                $this->filterBuilder->setField("{$field}.from");
                $this->filterBuilder->setValue($condition['from']);
                $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->create());
            }
            if (!empty($condition['to'])) {
                $this->filterBuilder->setField("{$field}.to");
                $this->filterBuilder->setValue($condition['to']);
                $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->create());
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     * @since 101.0.4
     */
    public function clear()
    {
        $this->searchResult = null;
        $this->setFlag('has_category_filter', false);

        return parent::clear();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     * @since 101.0.4
     */
    protected function _reset()
    {
        $this->searchResult = null;
        $this->setFlag('has_category_filter', false);

        return parent::_reset();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @since 101.0.4
     */
    public function _loadEntities($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
    {
        $this->getEntity();

        $this->printLogQuery($printQuery, $logQuery);
        /**
         * Prepare select query
         * @var string $query
         */
        $query = $this->getSelect();
        try {
            $rows = $this->_fetchAll($query);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->printLogQuery(false, true, $query);
            throw $e;
        }

        $position = 0;
        foreach ($rows as $value) {
            if ($this->getFlag('has_category_filter')) {
                $value['cat_index_position'] = $position++;
            }
            $object = $this->getNewEmptyItem()->setData($value);
            $this->addItem($object);
            if (isset($this->_itemsById[$object->getId()])) {
                $this->_itemsById[$object->getId()][] = $object;
            } else {
                $this->_itemsById[$object->getId()] = [$object];
            }
        }
        if ($this->getFlag('has_category_filter')) {
            $this->setFlag('has_category_filter', false);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add search query filter
     *
     * @param string $query
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addSearchFilter($query)
    {
        $this->queryText = trim($this->queryText . ' ' . $query);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function setOrder($attribute, $dir = Select::SQL_DESC)
    {
        $this->setSearchOrder($attribute, $dir);
        if ($this->defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker->isApplicable()) {
            parent::setOrder($attribute, $dir);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add attribute to sort order.
     *
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param string $dir
     * @return $this
     * @since 101.0.2
     */
    public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
    {
        if ($this->defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker->isApplicable()) {
            parent::addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
        } else {
            $this->setOrder($attribute, $dir);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        if ($this->isLoaded()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->searchRequestName !== 'quick_search_container'
            || ($this->queryText && strlen(trim($this->queryText)))
        ) {
            $this->prepareSearchTermFilter();
            $this->preparePriceAggregation();
             
            /* Custom Code for SKU start */

            $this->filterBuilder->setField('show_category');
            $this->filterBuilder->setValue('1');
            $this->filterBuilder->setConditionType('eq');

            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->create());

            /* Custom Code for SKU over */

            $searchCriteria = $this->getSearchCriteriaResolver()->resolve();
            try {
                $this->searchResult =  $this->getSearch()->search($searchCriteria);
                $this->_totalRecords = $this->getTotalRecordsResolver($this->searchResult)->resolve();
            } catch (EmptyRequestDataException $e) {
                $this->searchResult = $this->createEmptyResult();
            } catch (NonExistingRequestNameException $e) {
                $this->_logger->error($e->getMessage());
                throw new LocalizedException(__('An error occurred. For details, see the error log.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->searchResult = $this->createEmptyResult();
        }

        $this->getSearchResultApplier($this->searchResult)->apply();
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
        
        
        // $debugBackTrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
        // foreach ($debugBackTrace as $item) {
            // echo @$item['class'] . @$item['type'] . @$item['function'] . "\n";
        // }
    }
   

    /**
     * Create empty search result
     *
     * @return SearchResultInterface
     */
    private function createEmptyResult()
    {
        return $this->searchResultFactory->create()->setItems([]);
    }

    /**
     * Set sort order for search query.
     *
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $direction
     * @return void
     */
    private function setSearchOrder($field, $direction)
    {
        $field = (string)$this->_getMappedField($field);
        $direction = strtoupper($direction) == self::SORT_ORDER_ASC ? self::SORT_ORDER_ASC : self::SORT_ORDER_DESC;

        $this->searchOrders[$field] = $direction;
    }

    /**
     * Get total records resolver.
     *
     * @param SearchResultInterface $searchResult
     * @return TotalRecordsResolverInterface
     */
    private function getTotalRecordsResolver(SearchResultInterface $searchResult): TotalRecordsResolverInterface
    {
        return $this->totalRecordsResolverFactory->create(
            [
            'searchResult' => $searchResult,
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get search criteria resolver.
     *
     * @return SearchCriteriaResolverInterface
     */
    private function getSearchCriteriaResolver(): SearchCriteriaResolverInterface
    {
        return $this->searchCriteriaResolverFactory->create(
            [
                'builder' => $this->getSearchCriteriaBuilder(),
                'collection' => $this,
                'searchRequestName' => $this->searchRequestName,
                'currentPage' => (int)$this->_curPage,
                'size' => $this->getPageSize(),
                'orders' => $this->searchOrders,
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get search result applier.
     *
     * @param SearchResultInterface $searchResult
     * @return SearchResultApplierInterface
     */
    private function getSearchResultApplier(SearchResultInterface $searchResult): SearchResultApplierInterface
    {
        return $this->searchResultApplierFactory->create(
            [
                'collection' => $this,
                'searchResult' => $searchResult,
                /** This variable sets by serOrder method, but doesn't have a getter method. */
                'orders' => $this->_orders,
                'size' => $this->getPageSize(),
                'currentPage' => (int)$this->_curPage,
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @since 100.2.3
     */
    protected function _beforeLoad()
    {
        /*
         * This order is required to force search results be the same
         * for the same requests and products with the same relevance
         * NOTE: this does not replace existing orders but ADDs one more
         */
        $this->setOrder('entity_id');
        return parent::_beforeLoad();
    }

    /**
     * Render filters.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _renderFilters()
    {
        $this->_filters = [];
        return parent::_renderFilters();
    }

    /**
     * Stub method for compatibility with other search engines
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setGeneralDefaultQuery()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return field faceted data from faceted search result
     *
     * @param string $field
     * @return array
     * @throws StateException
     */
    public function getFacetedData($field)
    {
        $this->_renderFilters();
        $result = [];
        $aggregations = $this->searchResult->getAggregations();
        // This behavior is for case with empty object when we got EmptyRequestDataException
        if (null !== $aggregations) {
            $bucket = $aggregations->getBucket($field . RequestGenerator::BUCKET_SUFFIX);
            if ($bucket) {
                foreach ($bucket->getValues() as $value) {
                    $metrics = $value->getMetrics();
                    $result[$metrics['value']] = $metrics;
                }
            } else {
                throw new StateException(__("The bucket doesn't exist."));
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Specify category filter for product collection
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addCategoryFilter(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category)
    {
        $this->addFieldToFilter('category_ids', $category->getId());
        /**
         * This changes need in backward compatible reasons for support dynamic improved algorithm
         * for price aggregation process.
         */
        if ($this->defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker->isApplicable()) {
            parent::addCategoryFilter($category);
        } else {
            $this->setFlag('has_category_filter', true);
            $this->_productLimitationPrice();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set product visibility filter for enabled products
     *
     * @param array $visibility
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setVisibility($visibility)
    {
        $this->addFieldToFilter('visibility', $visibility);
        /**
         * This changes need in backward compatible reasons for support dynamic improved algorithm
         * for price aggregation process.
         */
        if ($this->defaultFilterStrategyApplyChecker->isApplicable()) {
            parent::setVisibility($visibility);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare search term filter for text query.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function prepareSearchTermFilter(): void
    {
        if ($this->queryText) {
            $this->filterBuilder->setField('search_term');
            $this->filterBuilder->setValue($this->queryText);
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->create());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prepare price aggregation algorithm.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function preparePriceAggregation(): void
    {
        $priceRangeCalculation = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Dynamic\AlgorithmFactory::XML_PATH_RANGE_CALCULATION,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        if ($priceRangeCalculation) {
            $this->filterBuilder->setField('price_dynamic_algorithm');
            $this->filterBuilder->setValue($priceRangeCalculation);
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->create());
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me how can I acheive this that layered navigation show **show_category** with **yes/no**, But on the products show only that which have the attribute set to **show_category** with **Yes**.

For example I set 14 products to **show_category** attribute **yes** and its shown correctly in pagination too.

[image]

But Its show only products to **show_category** attribute **yes** in product filter but need to show both **show_category** attribute **yes** or **no**.

[image]